# How to remove spaces from the line after a given word?

Tags: text-processing, sql

Suppose I have a file.txt; the content of the file is:

```
insert into x values('a ','  b',' c ');
insert into x values('  m ','  n  ','  p   ');
```

I just want to remove spaces from each line after the word `values`.

Desired output:

```
insert into x values('a','b','c');
insert into x values('m','n','p');
```

Comment: if there is only one `(` or `values(` in the line, `awk` would be good choice... or you can use `perl` to perform substitution on string that is matched...

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e ':a' -e "s/\('[^' ]*\)  */\1/g" -e ta  file.txt
```

---

```
insert into x values('a','b','c');
insert into x values('m','n','p');
```

We use a looping mechanism in tandem to progressively scrub the spaces inside single quote pairs '...' that a line might have. Note this is assuming no TABs, but which can be handled just as well

```
sed -e ':a' -e "s/\('[^'[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1/g" -e ta
```

Comment: Why three `-e`, when it is possible writing without them? - `sed ":a; s/\('[^' ]*\)  */\1/g; ta" input.txt` For readability?

Comment: Yes, for readability. Note that what you've written will go into an infinite loop. We need at least one space for it to converge.

Comment: I checked it before adding to the comment - it was working, now copy from comment - get infinite loop. Compared this two version and found, that 2 spaces after `\)` were converted to one. And it is cause the unworking command, yes. It is browser squeeze two spaces to one. Look, here 5 spaces between letters 'A': A     A. But only one is displayed. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433493/why-do-multiple-spaces-in-an-html-file-show-up-as-single-spaces-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have already inserted these values into the table, you may trim them of their space characters.

Assuming also that the columns in the table are called `c1`, `c2` and `c3`:

```
UPDATE x SET c1 = TRIM(c1), c2 = TRIM(c2), c3 = TRIM(c3);
```

The `TRIM()` function will remove both leading and trailing spaces.

If you want to test this on a temporary table first:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM x;
UPDATE t SET c1 = TRIM(c1), c2 = TRIM(c2), c3 = TRIM(c3);
SELECT * from t;
```

... or just

```
SELECT TRIM(c1), TRIM(c2), TRIM(c3) FROM x;
```

which wouldn't change anything in the database at all.

---

An SQL tip: When inserting values, do mention the names of the columns:

```
INSERT INTO x (c1, c2, c3) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

This both serves as documentation and allows you to change the schema of the table (inserting new columns or rearranging columns) without having to hunt down and change every `INSERT` statement in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`awk -F '(' '{ gsub(" ","",$2); print $1 FS $2; }' input.txt`

**Explanation**

1. Divide the string by the '**(**' sign - have two fields now:
   `$1 = insert into x values`
   `$2 = 'a ','  b',' c ');`
2. process **$2** field, substituting all spaces to nothing.
3. assembling new string:
   **$1** (not changed) + **FS** (left bracket sign) + **$2** (processed, without spaces now).

**Output:**

```
insert into x values('a','b','c');
insert into x values('m','n','p');
```